# It's possible to create a 3D or 2.5D video/animtation using the alembic file from photogrammetry?

Tags: animation, alembic, photogrammetry

my interest is about how create fast renders with the images aligned by photogrammetry. I think it's appropiate to use the alembic file (*.abc) from a a photogrammetry software such as meshroom.

I found examples with meshroom using the alembic file to create a sequence of the photogrammetry model, but my interes it's use the parallax between this images that are already aligned to create a 3D/2.5D animation.

Could be a possible solution to use all the images as background images? Can I render as background hundred of images?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome Joancalad! Sure, that's possible. The alembic file contains the cameras so you can set the images as background, project the images or even calculate new camera positions. Suggest to edit your question according to: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask